# How to call id from table in another table in laravel-8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Here I have `three tables` named `user`, `product`, `project`
In the `project table`, I have two foreignId named `user_id` and `product_id`

I want to show project table data using the index method in `ProjectController.php`

Here I can call user_id in the index method but I cant call product_id. Thanks for help
This is my index method in ProjectController.php

How to write where for product_id? I can`t get product_id value

```
public function index()
{
$projects = Project::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id')->latest()           ->paginate(20);
return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
       ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

This is products table products.php

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('detail');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

This is projects table projects.php

```
 Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('chapter_name', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('sub_section_name', 500)->nullable();
            $table->string('title_1', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('description_1', 5000)->nullable();
            $table->string('image_1', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('image_2', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('image_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('title_2', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('description_2', 5000)->nullable();
            $table->string('title_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('description_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('video_1', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('video_2', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('video_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger ('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            // $table->foreignId('product_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
        });
```

This is ProjetcImport.php

```
return new Project([
            'chapter_name'     => $row['chapter_name'],
            'sub_section_name'    => $row['sub_section_name'],
            'title_1'    => $row['title_1'],
            'description_1'    => $row['description_1'],
            'image_1'    => $row['image_1'],
            'image_2'    => $row['image_2'],
            'image_3'    => $row['image_3'],
            'title_2'    => $row['title_2'],
            'description_2'    => $row['description_2'],
            'title_3'    => $row['title_3'],
            'description_3'    => $row['description_3'],
            'video_1'    => $row['video_1'],
            'video_2'    => $row['video_2'],
            'video_3'    => $row['video_3'],
            'user_id'    => auth()->user()->id,
            'product_id'    => Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id'))
            // 'product_id' => id()->id
        ]);
```

Comment: based on which condition product_id added?

Comment: I don`t want to add auth condition here I just want produtc_id will work as foreignId in the projects table. It will take products id. one to many relationship one product will have many projects

Comment: add table structure

Comment: You can see i have edit my post

Comment: okay then got product_id got it based on user_id?

Comment: Like, Project::whereIn('product_id',Products::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('product_id')->toArray())->latest(); i not get it you question properly but may this helps out

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `product_id` from `products` where `user_id` = 1) Now I have This error

Comment: okay then got product_id got it based on user_id? Yes I want this

Comment: Project::whereIn('product_id',Products::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray();

Comment: afrer this i have compact(): Undefined variable $projects error so i have done this $projects = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray());
now I have This error BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::links() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php) I have edit my post i give my index.blode.php here Please check it I am sutck on this 1.5 days

Comment: Project::whereIn('product_id',Products::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray())->latest()->paginate(20);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Project::whereIn('product_id',Products::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray())->latest()->paginate(20);
```

I hope it would work for you.

Comment: Its work I need little more help I have to call same this in my projetcImport.php can you help

Comment: Okay please add other question with table structure.

Comment: Please try This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901512/call-id-from-product-table-in-projects-table-as-forignid-name-product-id-in-lara